# Numpy ndarray sort values by row and then exclude indices

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy.ndarray as follows:

```
from numpy import array
a = array( [[1,1,0.4], [1,1,0.3],[0.4,0.3,1]] )

array([[ 1. ,  1. ,  0.4],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  0.3],
       [ 0.4,  0.3,  1. ]])
```

Here is the columns:

```
dataidx = array( [1,2,3] )
```

I want to sort the values of the array above by row and then specify relevant dataidx:

```
indices = np.argsort(-a, axis=1)
result = np.hstack((dataidx[:, None], dataidx[indices]))
print(result)
[[1 1 2 3]
 [2 1 2 3]
 [3 3 1 2]]
```

For each row, how can I exclude the dataidx based on the first column like below?

```
[[1 2 3]
 [2 1 3]
 [3 1 2]]
```

Comment: Could there be more than two duplicates in any row? If so, should be exclude all? If exclude all, how do we maintain the 2D format?

Comment: there is no duplicate in each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
In [56]: m = result.shape[0]

In [57]: mask = np.c_[[True]*m,result[:,1:] != result[:,0,None]]

In [58]: result[mask].reshape(m,-1)
Out[58]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 2]])
```

Here's another -

```
In [105]: rm_idx = (result[:,1:] == result[:,0,None]).argmax(1)+1

In [106]: mask = np.ones(result.shape, dtype=bool)

In [107]: mask[np.arange(len(rm_idx)), rm_idx] = 0

In [108]: result[mask].reshape(result.shape[0],-1)
Out[108]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 2]])
```